# Unwanted list of linguistic abbreviations: leipzig and glossaries

Tags: glossaries, leipzig

I am working on my dissertation and use `leipzig` and `glossaries` to create the list of abbreviations from the glossed linguistic examples.

The first problem that I had was that only some of the predefined `leipzig` abbreviations were created in the Abbreviation section. In addition to that, I needed new glosses, which I  created with `newleipzig{}` but the abbreviation list didn't update anymore. Today, I added `\glsaddall` and generated the complete predefined list of Leipzig abbreviations including the new ones I had created.  Now I can't get rid of the extense list of abbreviations since it includes abbreviations that are not part of my examples. Here is MWE:

```latex
\usepackage[toc]{glossaries}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%Glosses & related packages
\usepackage[toc,block]{leipzig}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\noautomath 
\makeglossaries
\newcommand{\Tposs}{{\Third}{\Poss}}%New fusional gloss based on predefined ones
\newleipzig{dsit}{dsit}{sitting}
\newleipzig{dgng}{dgng}{going,far}
\newleipzig{coord}{coord}{coordinant}
\newleipzig{locor}{locor}{locative-orientative}
\newleipzig{disc}{disc}{discourse maker}
\newleipzig{trvz}{trvz}{transitivizer} %Method to include new glosses
\newcommand{\Tintr}{{\Third}{\Intr}}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\pagenumbering{roman}
 \tableofcontents
 \newpage
 \printglosses
 \listoffigures 
 \clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{Introduction}
The suffix \textit{\textipa{-ta{\textglotstop}}} can in fact be used to express reciprocal constructions and occurs as the rightmost suffix of the verb morphological structure, as shown in (\ref{reciprocal marking}).    


\begin{exe}
\ex \label{reciprocal marking}
\begin{xlist}
\ex[] {\gll so i-aqaya yim      i-owa\textipa{\textscg}an\\
         \Dgng{} \Tposs{}-brother \Fsg{} \Third{}-hit\\
\vspace{-1mm}\trans `My brother hit me.'\hfill(include localization)}
%remember the \vspace{•} command to fix the spacing in the translation.

\ex[] {\gll d\textipa{\textyogh}i yale-\textipa{\textfishhookr} n-owa\textipa{\textscg}an-te\textipa{\textg}-\textbf{ta\textipa{\textglotstop}}\\
            \Dgng{} man-\Pl{} \Third{}III-hit-\Prog-\Recp{}\\%Define a new command for the determiner .GNG
\vspace{-1mm}\trans `The men are fighting each other.'  \hfill(mocCA191017\_02)}
\end{xlist}
\end{exe}
```

[image]

Comment: First: your MWE does'nt work for me. Second: did you run 'make makeglossary' again, so you gave the program the opportunity to update its list of abbreviations? But before that: delete the files regarding only your glossary (they end with -glg, -glo and -gls) to be sure.

Comment: Thanks, @Venez. Where do I find those files? I've looked for them but I can't find them. Also, I did run makeglossary before I posted this but the problem persisted. I'll edit the MWE so you can compile it. I forgot the actual glossed example.

Comment: Nope, still not working (btw: MWE should start with 'documentclass', but my errors are starting with '\textipa{-ta{\textglotstop}}'). You should find the files in your folder besides your main document.

Answer (score 1):

Well, that's working for me. So if you can compile it as a standalone, you should clean your folder or the error is somewhere else to find.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[toc]{glossaries}

\usepackage[toc,block]{leipzig}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\noautomath 
\makeglossaries
\newleipzig{dsit}{dsit}{sitting}
\newleipzig{dgng}{dgng}{going,far}

\newcommand{\Tposs}{{\Third}{\Poss}}
\newcommand{\Tintr}{{\Third}{\Intr}}

\begin{document}
\printglosses
\newpage
The suffix (placeholder) can in fact be used to express reciprocal constructions and occurs as the rightmost suffix of the verb morphological structure, as shown in (\ref{reciprocal marking}).    
\begin{exe}
    \ex \label{reciprocal marking}
    \begin{xlist}
        \ex[] {\gll so i-aqaya yim      i-owaan\\
            \Dgng{} \Tposs{}-brother \Fsg{} \Third{}-hit\\
            \vspace{-1mm}\trans `My brother hit me.'\hfill(include localization)
        }
    \end{xlist}
\end{exe}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Venez. It works now. For some reason that I don't understand very well, makeglossaries is working now and produced the right abbreviations.